# typeof fn == "function" but fn() not supported

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, internet-explorer-8, frameset

I unfortunately have to work on some code with involves heavy frameset manipulation.  I have one frame loading data via jQuery AJAX into another frame, like so:

```
var lookUpDiv = $("<span />", top.frames["Main"].document)
.attr("id", "lookUpDiv")
.css({
   "background-color": "#ffffff",
   "margin": "10px",
   "overflow-y": "auto",
   "overflow-x": "hidden",
   "max-height": "100%",
   "display": (notIE8 ? "inline-block" : "inline"),
   "text-align": "center",
   "border-radius": "25px"
})
.text("Loading: Please Wait.")
.load("associateLookup-1.asp")
.appendTo(centeringDiv);
```

Among that data, there are a few functions being loaded.  I had a problem with them not being acessable to `top.frames["Main"]` but I solved that by declaring my functions as such:

```
var main = top.frames["Main"];

main.closePopup = function () {
    alert("");
}
```

This works in all the browsers I've tried except for ie8.  Unfortunately, most of our clients use ie8 so getting this to work is an absolute must.  I went into the js console and found some interesting results from tests:

```
top.frames["Main"].closePopup == {...}
typeof top.frames["Main"].closePopup == "function"
top.frames["Main"].closePopup()
"Object doesn't support this property or method"
```

Does anyone kn ow why I can't call this function?

Comment: Are you using JQueryMigrate?

Comment: No, I hadn't heard of it.  I'll take a look at it but right now I'm not using it.

Comment: Is `typeof top.frames["Main"].closePopup == "function"` true?

Comment: Yes.  If I run `typeof top.frames["Main"].closePopup == "function"` it returns true.